# Commutation BLDC Motor with Complementary PWM produces slower speeds than Independent PWM

Tags: stm32, pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, stm32cubeide

'"a complementary PWM can be used, which will also reduce the power dissipation in the devices".

That means using Complementary PWM makes the MOSFET cooler. However, in my program, using Complementary PWM makes two MOSFETs (half bridge for phase A) overheat, besides that my BLDC speed is slower than using Independent PWM.

From the experiment, using an 850kv motor with 11.35v lipo battery and 50% duty cycle pwm. Independent PWM produces speeds of around **4800 rpm** while using Complementary PWM around **4100 rpm**. I'm using a STM32F103 mcu.

I've added dead time insertion in my program. Dead time I use is around 400ns.

This is the code snippet for commutation that I used:

```
void AH_BL() {
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3); //Disable PWM CH 3.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);

    TIM1->CCR1 = dutyCycle; //Set DutyCycle Pin AH.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
}

void AH_CL() {
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2); //Disable PWM CH 2.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

    TIM1->CCR3 = 0; //Set Pin CL to High.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
}

void BH_CL() {
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1); //Disable PWM CH 1.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

    TIM1->CCR2 = dutyCycle; //Set DutyCycle Pin BH.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
}

void BH_AL() {
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3); //Disable PWM CH 3.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);

    TIM1->CCR1 = 0; //Set Pin AL to High.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
}

void CH_AL() {
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2); //Disable PWM CH 2.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);

    TIM1->CCR3 = dutyCycle; //Set DutyCycle Pin CH.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_3);
}

void CH_BL() {
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1); //Disable PWM CH 1.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

    TIM1->CCR2 = 0; //Set Pin BL to High.
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
    HAL_TIMEx_PWMN_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
}
```

I have tried 10 Khz, 30 Khz, and 50 Khz frequencies. The result is a slightly faster 50khz frequency but much faster using independent PWM.

What makes my code using complementary pwm produce slower speeds than using independent pwm?

This is the schematic that I used:

*Except the pin that I use is different from the schematic, because it was originally designed only for pwm independent pins

[image]

Comment: Speaking in terms of motor speeds is quite meaningless. You should grab your scope and see some waveforms.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your full schematic with actual component values. The more you put into that, the more info' people have got to help you get an answer. As it stands, it's impossible to answer properly.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks for the suggestion, I've added my schematic.

Comment: Sounds like you've made a logical mistake, and instead of dead time you've implemented the time of guaranteed overlapping of H/L inputs to gate drivers. This would explain the overheating of one pair of mosfets and the power loss.

Comment: @Vlad, can you point to whereabouts you see that in the posted schematic and source code?